# tabularx and textwidth

Tags: tables, tabularx

I'd like to insert a 3-columm table in my project, but I am facing problems trying to fit text in a multicolumm cell. Here is my code:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c X c|}
\hline

\multicolumn{1}{|c}{} & 
\multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{ cell0: text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text }\\
\hline

cell1 & cell2: text text text text text text text text & cell3\\

\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}
```

The problem is, whenever I use the hsize command to make the text fit into cell0 properly, cell2 in the following line loses its automatic adjustment to text and acquires fixed width (which I do not want). So, how can I adjust the text in cell0 at the same time that cell2 keeps the automatic adjustment to text?

Comment: You prescribe width of `multicolumn` cells, consequently the columns' width, which it span, has this width. Since the first of them has defined width,  the second  is forced to adapt its width accordingly: in your case has the same width as the first of spanned columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculation of the usable width of the "cell0" object is incorrect. It would be (almost) correct if both underlying columns were of type `X`; however, that's not the case, is it?

To calculate the usable combined width of columns 2 and 3 correctly, I suggest you proceed as follows.

- First, find the cell in column 3 that determines the natural width of that column. This is usually done easily and reliably by visual inspection.
- Suppose the cell that defines the natural width of column 3 consists of the string `aratherlongword`. Its width may be determined by running

```
   \newlength\colwidth
   \settowidth\colwidth{aratherlongword}
```

- Then the usable combined width of columns 2 and 3 may be calculated as

```
   \hsize=\dimexpr\hsize+\colwidth+2\tabcolsep\relax
```

---

A full MWE (note that I've discarded `\multicolumn{1}{|c}{}` since it's redundant.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\newlength\colwidth
\settowidth\colwidth{aratherlongword}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c X c|}
\hline
& \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr\hsize+\colwidth+2\tabcolsep\relax}X|}{%
  cell0: text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text }\\
\hline
cell1 & cell2: text text text text text text text text & aratherlongword\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```